# C: Make generic iteration function?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, iteration

I have an struct which defines an array of structs, each of which contain a couple more arrays. These inner arrays define my 'datasets'.

In numerous places, I wish to iterate over all the datasets. To avoid 3 nested loops, I loop over the total number of datasets and have a few if statements to keep track of which array I need to access. It looks like this:

```
  int datasetCount = 0;
  int defendedDatasetCount = 0;
  int i;
  Dataset *ds;
  for (i = 0 ; i < totalDatasets ; i++)
  {
    // If we have passed the number of datasets in this group, move to the next group
    if (datasetCount == (dg->nDatasets + dg->nDefDatasets))
    {
        dg++;
        datasetCount = 0;
        defendedDatasetCount = 0;
    }

    // If we have gone through all the (undefended) datasets, read from thte defended datasets
    if (datasetCount >= dg->nDatasets)
    {
        ds = &(dg->defDatasets[defendedDatasetCount]);
        defendedDatasetCount++;

    }
    else
    {
        ds = &(dg->datasets[datasetCount]);
    }
```

where `dg` is the pointer to a struct which is simply an array of structs and a `size` counter.

I find myself repeating this boilerplate code for iterating through the datasets in a few functions which do different things.

I'm struggling to be able to come up with something like this:

```
while (give_me_next_dataset(dg) == TRUE)
{
    ...
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: Sidenote: use the standard bool types (`_Bool` or `stdbool.h`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but the proposed API isn't very nice. You're going to have to put iteration state somewhere, and you're not leaving any room for that.

I would propose something like:

```
struct DgIter {
  struct Dg *dg;
  size_t index;
  size_t dataSet;
};
```

Then you can have functions like:

```
struct DgIter iter_start(struct Dg *dg)
{
  const struct DgIter iter = { dg, 0, 0 };
  return iter;
}

void * iter_next_dataset(struct DgIter *iter)
{
  // check if there is a current dataset, else return NULL
  // update fields in iter as necessary
}
```

Comment: Ok, i see. so each time I want to iterate, I would do something like:
`struct DgIter it = iter_start(dg); while(iter_next_dataset(&it) != NULL)` ?

Comment: @jramm Exactly. That packages up the act of iterating in an API and makes it easy to do in the rest of the code.